# Passing struct to a function gets 'undefined reference to' error

Tags: c, struct

I ran into an issue during my practice session with C that hopefully someone at stack overflow can help me with. The back story is that I wanted to get a solid understanding of how to use structs so I started playing with the concept but ran into a problem when I started using arrays and started passing structs to a function.

When I compile my code using G++ in Linux I get a compile error:

```
/tmp/ccCjoSgv.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `indexBooks(int, book)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out on my own looking through similar Stack Overflow problems but still couldn't understand why I was getting this compile error. Can anyone give their expertise and explain why I am getting these errors?

**book.h**

```
struct book{
  char title[100];
  char author[100];
  unsigned int bin;
};
```

**main includes**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "books.h"
```

**main prototypes**

```
void askUsrNum(int*);
void indexBooks(int, struct book science);
```

**inside main()**

```
int usrNum;
struct book science[usrNum];
... plus the code below...
```

**main function calls**

```
askUsrNum(&usrNum); //ask user how many books to catalog
indexBooks(usrNum, *science);   //record the books using struct
```

**actual functions**

```
void askUsrNum(int *usrNum){
    printf("How many books are you cataloging: ");
    scanf("%i", usrNum);

    return;
}

void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[]){

   int i = 0;
   int limit = (usrNum -1);
   for(i = 0; i <= limit; i++){
       printf("Book %i Title: ", i+1);
       scanf("%s", science[i].title);

       printf("Book %i Author: ", i+1);
       scanf("%s", science[i].author);

       printf("Book %i BIN: ", i+1);
       scanf("%i", &science[i].bin);

       printf("\n");    //newline

       return;
   }
}
```

Comment: Prototype: `void indexBooks(int, struct book science);` Implementation: `void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[])` See the difference?

Comment: g++ is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler (in the first place). So ist that supposed to be C or C++ code? They are different languages. Remove the unrelated tag and edit your text!

Comment: wow that was silly ... thank you!

Comment: You still seem to use g++!

Comment: g++ is a habit i formed when i was learning c++. I will use gcc. THank you for pointing that out btw (:

Answer (score 5):

The prototype you declared doesn't match your function definition. You are declaring:

```
void indexBooks(int, struct book science);
```

But you're *defining*:

```
void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[])
```

Note the brackets in the definition. Your declaration declares a function which takes a single `struct book` argument, but the definition takes an **array** of `struct book`s. You should change the declaration to `void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[])`.

Answer (score 4):

Your function prototype and implementation do not match:

Prototype:

```
void indexBooks(int, struct book science);  // science should be an array instead
```

Implementation:

```
void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[])
```

It looks like your prototype is wrong, `indexBooks()` is taking an array of struct instead of individual struct.

---

You should first try to fix the prototype first:

```
void indexBooks(int, struct book science[]);
```

---

Also in `main`, you should pass the whole array instead of its first element:

```
indexBooks(usrNum, *science); //record the books using struct // incorrect
```

should be

```
indexBooks(usrNum, science);
```

Comment: No problem. Wording is a bit off here: "instead of pointer to array" OP isn't sending a pointer, they are dereferencing the pointer and accidentally sending a copy of the first element. Or they would be if it compiled.

Answer (score 4):

Prototype and function do not match:

```
void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science);
void indexBooks(int usrNum, struct book science[]){
```

One is an array one is a struct....

Comment: Both are correct depending on what you are intending to do, given that the function references each array address the second one is correct (with []), update the prototype to include the square brackets.